# Merge two videos with transparency in ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, transparency

I have two videos merged into one file using below command. Unfortunately second video covers first video and it is not visible. How to make second video transparent (eg. 50%)?

```
ffmpeg
    -i in1.mp4 -i in2.mp4
    -filter_complex "nullsrc=size=480x360 [base];
        [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=480x360 [top];
        [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=480x360 [bottom];
        [base][top] overlay=shortest=1 [temp];
        [temp][bottom] overlay=shortest=1"
    -acodec libvo_aacenc -vcodec libx264 out.pm4
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but `libvo_aacenc` is a crappy AAC encoder. Use `-c:a aac` instead. If `ffmpeg` provides an error mentioning that `aac` is experimental then upgrade your `ffmpeg` because `aac` is no longer experimental.

Comment: Do both inputs contain audio? If yes, how do you want to deal with the audio? With your command `ffmpeg` will choose audio from one input. You should always include the complete console output from your command when asking for `ffmpeg` help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg \
    -i in1.mp4 -i in2.mp4 \
    -filter_complex " \
        [0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=480x360[top]; \
        [1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=480x360, \
             format=yuva420p,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5[bottom]; \
        [top][bottom]overlay=shortest=1" \
    -acodec libvo_aacenc -vcodec libx264 out.mp4
```

Set `aa` to the opacity value needed.

Comment: This almost works for me except the main video (in1.mp4) stops showing video after in2.mp4 has finished, however the audio from in1.mp4 does continue for the duration of the video, just the video is "paused"

Comment: can you also explain the `top` and `bottom` my overlay sits left aligned and I'd like it centered, even if I have to specify the number of pixels it needs to move over

Comment: @Mulvya this works good, any way to repeat the shortest video?

Comment: If you know which input is shortest, its filterchain should be `scale=480x360,loop=-1:99999:0,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS`. where 99999 is a number equal or greater than its frame count.

Comment: How to mix sound in addition to video? With above command audio channel from input #0 is used.